# Custom paypal checkout button showing inside iframe

Tags: javascript, paypal

I want to keep the credit card form UI keep open inside my iframe. But Sometimes it open inside, sometimes with the new window. How can I keep it only open inside my iframe?

[image: This is my site image]

Here is the code:

```
loadScript({
    "client-id": content['client_id'],
    "data-client-token": content['client_token'],
    "currency": "JPY",
    "data-order-id": this.order_id,
    "locale": 'ja_JP'
}).then((paypal) => {
    paypal.Buttons({
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      createOrder: (data, actions) => {
        this.cancelDisabled = true;
        return Promise.resolve(this.order_id);
      },
      onApprove: (data, actions) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
       return actions.order.capture().then((details) => {
         this.$api.fetch(`/payment-sessions/${this.paymentSession.id}/send_request/?request=payment-capture-done&to=operator,payer`)
       });
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        this.cancelDisabled = false;
        console.error(err);
      },
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
      onCancel: (data, actions) => {
        this.cancelDisabled = false;
      }
    }).render("#paypal-button-container")
    .then(() => {
      let btn = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container')
      btn.style.display = 'unset';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue caused by a target reference somewhere in your code. Try adding this code to check and see if this issue is caused by a window or tab redirect. Note that this is not a solution but a debug method to identify your problem.

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').removeAttr('target');
```

Comment: I didn't find a tag with the target blank in my code. The issue is when click to pay with the credit card button(The button generated by Paypal) is sometimes open in a separate window. So I don't think it's an issue from my side.

Comment: that's weird 1 suggestion would be to disable any new window redirects from your page. but its not really a solution